# Can't load jQuery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm an absolute beginner in web development. I have an html, css and javascript file. I want to simply change the background color of a button, but unfortunately it doesn't work. All the files (including jquery library) are placed in a folder. Any clue is appreciated.

html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button">Click!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button_clicked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

javascript codes:

```
var clicked = function(){
    $('.button').clicked(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
    });
};

$(document).ready(clicked);
```

Comment: If the jqery file is in the same foolder of your html page Try uisng ./ (dot/) for relative path   <script src="./jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Open up the developer console. Do you see errors in the console? Where is the JavaScript code located? I see no where where you JS file is located in that html document.

Comment: it writes: **jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).clicked is not a function clicked@file:///C:/Users/Ehsan/Desktop/New%20folder/code.js:2:2
g/</j@file:///C:/Users/Ehsan/Desktop/New%20folder/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29566
g/</k<@file:///C:/Users/Ehsan/Desktop/New%20folder/jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2:29882
 undefined**

Comment: You may be looking for jQuery's [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/), as opposed to `clicked()`.

Comment: Thanks to scaisEdge and epascarello and @showdev. I changed the **clicked** function to **click** and it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a simple typo. Notice that your variable name is defined as `clicked` but the function in jQuery is `click()`. So if you make the following change it should work just fine:

```
var clicked = function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
});
};

$(document).ready(clicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code :**

```js
function change_color()
{
  var NAME = document.getElementById("button");
    var currentClass = NAME.className;
    if (currentClass == "button") { // Check the current class name
        NAME.className = "button_clicked";   // Set other class name
    } else {
        NAME.className = "button";  // Otherwise, use `second_name`
    }   
}
```

```css
.button ,.button_clicked {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button_clicked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button class="button" id="button" onclick="change_color()">Click!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code does work, I would argue that Javascript should be fully removed from the HTML as you want to keep functionality and markup separated. It will make maintenance easier and prevent potential issues with syndication (if applicable) Also, I would recommend modifying the CSS you wrote here as well as the Javascript to ADD the button_clicked class to .button as opposed to changing the class name to reduce the amount of needed CSS. In that case you could remove all but the background color on the button_clicked class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the named function - assign the click event behaviour directly to click of the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
      });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("button_clicked");
    });
  });
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button_clicked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button">Click Me</button>
```